# Two wifi networks not appearing on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, drivers, wifi-configuration

i have a fujitsu lifebook T935  windows 10 64bit.  it sees neighboring wifi networks, but not my two networks and it works on the network at work no issues.  i have other devices connected to both of my wifi networks.

following trouble shooting has been done
turn it off and on
install all driver updates and windows update
ipconfig / commands
reverted back to an old save point 
wifi ap is up to date on its firmware and set to discoverable
uninstalled wifi adapter, restarted, and reinstalled it.
checked that it works on the netowrk with a wired connection, it does.
did a bunch of stuff one random page said to do involving the windows store.
checked that my networks are on both 2.4 and 5ghz and set the channel manually to the 2.4ghz one to channel 1, formerly on Auto
connected it to my phones hot spot as well
checked all power settings for the adapter, looked over adapter settings.
got desperate and ran the windows troubleshooters as well.4

i am thinking maybe the adapter is just borked but i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that those two networks SSIDs are set to hidden, and that's why they don't appear in the available network list.

From one of your other devices, can you access your networks management console (usually via a web browser) and check if the SSIDs for those networks are set to visible?

If your laptop sees neighboring networks, it should see yours as well. If it doesn't, it means that either they're hidden, or that your WiFi adapter can't play with them for some reason.

In your WiFi adapter properties, can you check under the Advanced tab if the Bandwidth is set to 20_40MHz, and the Roaming sensitivity is on Low?

Comment: ssids are not hidden.  changed the settings you suggested and restarted.  no change.  i actually am on another laptop right now connected to the wifi in question and my phone is using it as well.